# Oracle View not working correctly using Case when condition

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, view, case-when

For `M_DESCR` field I am trying to put the value as `'C'` when `altype = 'Cash total'`, when `altype = 'Other total'` then I want value as `'O'` else it should be `null`. When I am trying to do the same in my first `union all` condition then nothing has been changed for field `M_DESCR`.

Also I want to remove field `ALTYPE` from view at the end when all the calculation has been done but don't know how to do that.

Comment: There is some fundamental wrong with your view. 1. There is no value as  `allocationassettype = 'Cash total' ` or `llocationassettype = 'Other total'` in  table `is_test` . 2. second and third union gives only one row with all the fields having null value. 3. I assume you are trying to access the result of 2nd and 3rd union in the 1st union which is not possible. Could you clarify these points and add expected result output also. 4.Removing `ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE` should not be an issue.

Comment: actually as you can see from first UNION i am just taking all the fields and in the second union and third union i am adding extra two rows with 'Cash Total' and 'Other Total' respectively with some kind of calculations which is currently working fine ....i want to remove ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE only after doing all the calculation as i am using this field for the same...

Comment: If you say so the second and third is fine its fine , using one level sub query should what you do and should not try to access it in first union which is logically doesn't make sense.

Comment: can you tell exactly how to do that ?

Comment: ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE is a column from the underlying table IS_TEST. So you could simply remove it from the projection of the view IS_ID without affecting your ability to reference it in the view's internal logic. However, you use ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE to identify `Cash total` and `Other total` summary lines, so it seems you do need the column in the view's projection after all. In short, it's not at all clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your question by providing sample data which covers **all your use cases** (hint: include some data for ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE which would trigger your conditional logic) and also by providing required output derived from that sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With what I understood may be you are looking for something like, ( Only thing I am little skeptical with the data set you provided but may be I am wrong)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW
    IS_ID
    (
        IDENTIFIER,
        IMPORT_DATE,
        EFFECTIVE_DATE,      
        FUND_QUOTE,
        FUND_QUOTE_CRNY,
        FUND_QUOTE_DATE,
        MEMBER_IDENTIFIER,        
        MEMBER_QUOTE_CRNY,
        MEMBER_QTY,
        MEMBER_QTY_TYPE,
        FORCE_FLAG,
        MEMBER_DESCR,
        MEMBER_RATIO,
        MEMBER_MARKETVALUE
    ) AS
SELECT
  IDENTIFIER,
  IMPORT_DATE,
  EFFECTIVE_DATE,      
  FUND_QUOTE,
  FUND_QUOTE_CRNY,
  FUND_QUOTE_DATE,
  MEMBER_IDENTIFIER,
  MEMBER_QUOTE_CRNY,
  MEMBER_QTY,
  MEMBER_QTY_TYPE,
  FORCE_FLAG,
  CASE 
       WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash total'
       THEN
       'C'
       WHEN allocationassettype = 'Other total'
       THEN
       'O'
       ELSE NULL
  END AS MEMBER_DESCR,
  MEMBER_RATIO,
  MEMBER_MARKETVALUE        
FROM
(
SELECT
    IDENTIFIER,
    IMPORT_DATE,
    EFFECTIVE_DATE,      
    FUND_QUOTE,
    FUND_QUOTE_CRNY,
    FUND_QUOTE_DATE,
    MEMBER_IDENTIFIER,
    MEMBER_QUOTE_CRNY,
    MEMBER_QTY,
    MEMBER_QTY_TYPE,
    FORCE_FLAG,
    MEMBER_DESCR,
    MEMBER_RATIO,
    MEMBER_MARKETVALUE,        
    ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE
FROM
    IS_TEST
WHERE
    ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE != 'Cash'
and MEMBER_IDENTIFIER is not null
UNION ALL
SELECT
    IDENTIFIER,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash'
            THEN member_ratio
            ELSE 0
        END),
    SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash'
            THEN member_marketvalue
            ELSE 0
        END),
    'Cash total'    
FROM
    IS_TEST
GROUP BY
    IDENTIFIER, MEMBER_DESCR
UNION ALL
SELECT
    IDENTIFIER,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
   NULL,
    100 - SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MEMBER_IDENTIFIER IS NOT NULL
            THEN member_ratio
            ELSE 0
        END) - SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash'
            THEN member_ratio
            ELSE 0
        END),
    SUM(member_marketvalue) - SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash'
            THEN member_marketvalue
            ELSE 0
        END) - SUM(
        CASE
            WHEN MEMBER_IDENTIFIER IS NOT NULL
            THEN member_marketvalue
            ELSE 0
        END),
    'Other total'    
FROM
    IS_TEST
GROUP BY
    IDENTIFIER
);
```

Comment: it complains for not group by expression for the third union where WHEN allocationassettype = 'Cash total'

Comment: It should not. check this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=57c5551a128494f72702d8f8608a1297

Comment: I have not modified the logic for second and third union rather just added the first union together with second and third into from clause so that we can access  `allocationassettype ` as you have mentioned in your original question

Comment: there is one issue sorry i didnt mention in question...there are below fields value for each identifier which are repetating and needs to be added for cash total and other total field also but we need to make sure group by only needed for Identifier field otherwise it will affect calculation logic...not sure if we need to add another union for this ? IMPORT_DATE,
            EFFECTIVE_DATE,            
            FUND_QUOTE_CRNY, MEMBER_QUOTE_CRNY,
            MEMBER_QTY_TYPE,            
            FORCE_FLAG,

Comment: If you say its always repeated as per the respective group by in union 2 and union 3 respectively then just use max() for all the fields you have mentioned. ( only question remains is what is the role of `MEMBER_DESCR` in 2nd union group by clause)

Comment: MEMBER_DESCR will remain as it is with cash total and other total......so if i remove MEMBER_DESCR in 2nd union group by clause then also its not affecting anything

Comment: i have created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63598820/apply-filter-in-oracle-view

Comment: @Symonds; No issue just not finding right time to look into. Could you test with `select * from IS_ID where not (nvl(MEMBER_DESCR,'X') = 'O' and member_ratio > = -5)` is this what you want ?

Comment: sorry no the IDENTIFIERS are still appearing in view where MEMBER_DESCR = 'O' and member_ratio < -5;

Comment: I want like this ....Select * from IS_ID where  MEMBER_DESCR = 'O' and member_ratio > -5;

Comment: Then just remove `not` and try or else just give me some sample output . may be i am not getting the point

Comment: `Select * from IS_ID where MEMBER_DESCR = 'O' and member_ratio > -5;.....then its giving me correct result of excluding the IDENTIFIER which i dont need in View.`  if its correct then you have what you want right ? or I would request you to add the full data set to the fiddle and comment or mark which should come and which shouldn't Unable to understand from the data set.

Answer (score -1):

I dont see any issue with the view created. You can simply remove ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE column from select list and view column list.

In the test case i can't see any value as described by you:

**

> allocationassettype = 'Cash total', when allocationassettype = 'Other
> total'

**