# Apply filter in Oracle View

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view

I have below view where i just wanted to apply small filter such that for example i want to ignore or remove all rows for each IDENTIFIER from the View where member_descr = 'O' and member_ratio < = -5.

I am not sure if i want to create new Union condition or apply filter where i am calculating value for member_ratio value for member_descr = 'O'

Currently in the fiddle we can see the member_ratio value is 15.32778 for member_descr = 'O' which is ok for Identifier I0000RTERER3 after calculation. But after calculation for member_descr = 'O'  if the member_ratio <= -5 then i want to ignore or remove all the rows for this identifier from view.

Comment: Do you mean not only the record with  `member_descr = 'O' the value of MEMBER_RATIO < -5 ` but also all the records with `LU0068337053` should be removed ?

Comment: yes all the records for LU0068337053 should be removed if the condition is not satisfied..

Comment: Also posted to https://community.oracle.com/thread/4345005

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood now we need `not exists` here,

```
select * 
  from IS_ID t1
  where not exists ( select 1
                       from IS_ID t2
                      where t1.identifier = t2.identifier
                        and (MEMBER_DESCR = 'O' and member_ratio < -5))
```

Comment: yes exactly i think this is fine...but how can i apply the same rule in View ? I think we need this it after calculation ?

Comment: Yes you are right but modifying the existing would be too much and I would recommend to create another view using this query instead modifying already kind of complex view .

Comment: Ohh is it not possible to apply the same in existing view ? i thought may be we need to apply extra union or filter ?

Comment: Yes it should be possible Symonds but i think lets keep the base view as it is and if you really need another filtered one why not create one ? a query should be fine but if it is something will be used in many places create another one. Creating view would not hurt anything.

Comment: We need to remove all the identifiers which matches to `MEMBER_DESCR = 'O' and member_ratio < -5` is the difficult part to achieve in the existing view. I will try it and update you in case a success.

Comment: can you please help me in this issue which is similar : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64009771/create-oracle-view-based-on-comparision-of-data-between-two-database-tables