# create oracle view based on comparision of data between two database tables

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view

I have below tables:

- I want to create View such that for `descr = 'O'` and for common `id_isin` field value from both tables, check the `ratio` field and take only the row where `ratio` field value is low.
- for `descr = 'O'` and if the id_isin exist in one table but not in another then take those rows(bidirectional)
- For all the rows where `descr ! = 'O'`, take all those rows from table `IS_ID_TST`.

Below is the expected output from view for example:

```
ID_ISIN   QUOTE_CRNY   DESCR           RATIO              ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE
L000123    USD              O              0.0769          Other total
L000129    USD              O              0.0669          Other total
D123458    USD              O              0.64039         Other total
M123456    USD              O              5.64039         Other total
F563458    USD              C              0.84039         Other total
G123456    USD              null           0.04039         Other total
L000123    USD              C              5.0769          Other total
```

Can i create View based on this conditions ?

Comment: There is some issue with the insert statement to the `IS_ID_TST` table ? Could you check and correct it ?

Comment: Your script doesn't even work. In table IS_ID_TST, you define FUND_QUOTE_CRNY as NUMBER(19,8).  But the value you try to insert into it is 'USD', resulting in "ORA-01722: invalid number"

Comment: i have corrected the script and tested it , it should work now

Comment: For point `for member_descr = 'O' and if the fund_isin exist in one table but not in another then take those rows` .......(1). Is it unidirectional from `IS_ID` to `IS_ID_TST` or bidirectional ?..(2). why for `fund_isin = D123458` only one row with low ratio bing taken but as per the logic both should be there in the output because its does exist in `IS_ID` but not in `IS_ID_TST` ?

Comment: its bidirectional, we have to consider both the tables for point second where member_descr = 'O'...for fund_isin = D123458 we just consider value where member_descr = 'O' from table IS_ID, thats why only one row has been taken, so basically we are considering table IS_ID only for condition member_descr = 'O'

Comment: @Symonds, I will check with new logic and update. More comments are also not allowed in SO. Its better to create a new question as you did. I will check and update.

Comment: @Sujit i have already created new question and also commented here below your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044272/create-oracle-view-to-compare-data-based-on-conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with below query, Please check I have put comments on the query. Ask if doesn't meet you r requirement or for any clarification.

```
CREATE VIEW v_combined_data AS
WITH combined_data
AS
(
SELECT t1.fund_isin
      ,t1.fund_quote_crny
      ,t1.member_descr
      ,t1.member_ratio
      ,t1.allocationassettype
      ,t2.fund_isin fund_isin_tst
      ,t2.fund_quote_crny fund_quote_crny_tst
      ,t2.member_descr member_descr_tst
      ,t2.member_ratio member_ratio_tst
      ,t2.allocationassettype allocationassettype_tst
FROM   is_id t1
FULL   OUTER JOIN is_id_tst t2
ON     t1.fund_isin = t2.fund_isin
AND    t1.fund_quote_crny = t2.fund_quote_crny
AND    t1.member_descr = t2.member_descr
)
-- for member_descr = 'O' and for common fund_isin field value from both tables, 
-- check the member_ratio field and take only the row where member_ratio field value is low.
SELECT d.fund_isin
      ,d.fund_quote_crny
      ,d.member_descr
      ,LEAST(d.member_ratio,d.member_ratio_tst) member_ratio
      ,d.allocationassettype
  FROM combined_data d
WHERE d.member_descr = 'O'
  AND d.fund_isin IS NOT NULL 
  AND d.fund_isin_tst IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
--for member_descr = 'O' and if the fund_isin exist in one table but not in another then take those rows(bidirectional)
--exists in IS_ID and not in IS_ID_TST
SELECT d.fund_isin
      ,d.fund_quote_crny
      ,d.member_descr
      ,d.member_ratio
      ,d.allocationassettype
  FROM combined_data d
WHERE d.member_descr = 'O'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM combined_data ci
                   WHERE ci.fund_isin_tst = d.fund_isin
                     AND ci.fund_quote_crny_tst = d.fund_quote_crny
                     AND ci.member_descr_tst = 'O')
UNION ALL
--for member_descr = 'O' and if the fund_isin exist in one table but not in another then take those rows(bidirectional)
--exists in IS_ID_TST and not in IS_ID
SELECT d.fund_isin_tst
      ,d.fund_quote_crny_tst
      ,d.member_descr_tst
      ,d.member_ratio_tst
      ,d.allocationassettype_tst
  FROM combined_data d
WHERE d.member_descr_tst = 'O'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                    FROM combined_data ci
                   WHERE ci.fund_isin = d.fund_isin_tst
                     AND ci.fund_quote_crny = d.fund_quote_crny_tst
                     AND ci.member_descr = 'O')
UNION ALL
--for all the rows where member_descr ! = 'O', take all those rows from table IS_ID_TST
SELECT d.fund_isin_tst
      ,d.fund_quote_crny_tst
      ,d.member_descr_tst
      ,d.member_ratio_tst
      ,d.allocationassettype_tst
  FROM combined_data d
WHERE d.fund_isin_tst IS NOT NULL
  AND (d.member_descr_tst != 'O' OR d.member_descr_tst IS NULL);
```

Comment: @Symonds, Just add `create view view_name as ` .at the top of the query....I will edit then. wait..

Comment: thanks very much this seems to be working ..i will just comment in case any question :)

Comment: You are welcome . Yes of course and I will try to answer :)

Comment: one question in FULL_OUTER_JOIN normally the join should be based only on FUND_ISIN field from both tables as this is the key to compare the data...why did you take the other fields also  t1.fund_quote_crny = t2.fund_quote_crny
AND    t1.member_descr = t2.member_descr ? its working fine if i provide only t1.fund_isin = t2.fund_isin...so can i keep it ?

Comment: also in the full outer join cant apply filter with member_descr = 'O'  which can improve performance ?

Comment: @Symonds, yes we can do but then you need to change the last union to actual table and filter accordingly for values other than `O`

Comment: ok then i will keep it as it is and i kept join condition only based on field fund_isin from both tables

Comment: i have updated question and added at the bottom insert statements and expected output

Comment: sorry i want to make slight change but i think its contradicting to current logic....there are fund_isin from IS_ID_TST table for member_descr = 'O' for which member_ratio < 0 then in this case it should always take the data from IS_ID_TST table and does not check and take the row from IS_ID table even if member_ratio is lower... for example check in output for fund_isin F000123

Comment: initially for fund_isin we are taking data from IS_ID table only where member_descr = 'O' but we need to take all data when member_ratio is lower from IS_ID table and for such fund_isin it should not take data from IS_ID_TST table check output find_isin L000123, D123458...i think here logic will contradict as at the end the logic is to take all the data from IS_ID_TST table where member_descr ! = 'O' otherwise there will be duplicate from both table for same FUND_ISIN? For all other cases we should take the data from IS_ID_TST table M123456, F563458, G123456

Comment: and as we decided to take all the data from IS_ID table where member_ratio is low and for which the fund_isin does not exist in IS_ID_TST table then we also dont need this condition AND t1.member_descr = t2.member_descr because the member_descr can be different from both the table for same fund_isin..

Comment: @ Sujit  i have created new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044272/create-oracle-view-to-compare-data-based-on-conditions

Comment: @ Sujit i have small question..i mentioned here in discussion chat can you please check: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222087/discussion-between-symonds-and-sujitmohanty30

Answer (score 2):

You need `LEAST()` function along with 3 subqueries combined with `UNION` clauses. Two of the subqueries should contain `FULL JOIN` among tables :

```
CREATE VIEW V_MEMBER_FUND AS    
SELECT i.fund_isin,
       i.member_descr,
       LEAST(i.member_ratio, t.member_ratio) AS member_ratio,
       i.allocationassettype
  FROM IS_ID i
  JOIN IS_ID_TST t
    ON t.fund_isin = i.fund_isin
   AND t.member_descr = i.member_descr
 WHERE i.member_descr = 'O'
UNION
SELECT LEAST(NVL(i.fund_isin,t.fund_isin),NVL(t.fund_isin,i.fund_isin)) AS fund_isin,
       LEAST(NVL(i.member_descr,t.member_descr),NVL(t.member_descr,i.member_descr)) AS member_descr,
       LEAST(NVL(i.member_ratio,t.member_ratio),NVL(t.member_ratio,i.member_ratio)) AS member_ratio,
       LEAST(NVL(i.allocationassettype,t.allocationassettype),NVL(t.allocationassettype,i.allocationassettype)) AS allocationassettype
  FROM IS_ID i
  FULL JOIN IS_ID_TST t
    ON t.fund_isin = i.fund_isin
 WHERE (i.member_descr = 'O' OR t.member_descr = 'O' )
   AND ( t.fund_isin IS NULL OR i.fund_isin IS NULL )
UNION
SELECT t.fund_isin,
       t.member_descr,
       t.member_ratio,
       t.allocationassettype
  FROM IS_ID i
 RIGHT JOIN IS_ID_TST t
    ON t.fund_isin = i.fund_isin
   AND t.member_descr = i.member_descr
 WHERE (NVL(i.member_descr,'XYZ') != 'O' OR NVL(t.member_descr,'XYZ') != 'O' )
   AND t.fund_isin IS NOT NULL
```

for the **first** case : Only need to return the minimum value in terms of member_ratio with `i.member_descr = 'O'` matches.

for the **second** case : Bidirectional(`FULL JOIN`) logic is told to be needed

for the **third** case : An **outer join** respective to the position of `IS_ID_TST` table(in the current case it's `RIGHT JOIN`)is needed along with non-equivalent values of `member_desct` to the value `'O'`(*even NULL values should be aliminated, and `NVL()` function is added for this aim* )

And all those subqueries specified within the three cases should be combined with `UNION` in order to provide row-wise combination including the elimination of the repeated rows.

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=ac8668f0436e82dbf6f1e1b6f1ad0749)</kbd>

Comment: thanks could be really helpful if you can just comment some part of logic ..specially where you are writing logic for 3 points which i mentioned ...

Comment: you're welcome @Symonds, I've added more explanation.

Comment: sorry i want to make slight change but i think its contradicting to current logic....there are fund_isin from IS_ID_TST table for member_descr = 'O' for which member_ratio < 0 then in this case it should always take the data from IS_ID_TST table and does not check and take the row from IS_ID table even if member_ratio is lower... for example check in output for fund_isin F000123

Comment: initially for fund_isin we are taking data from IS_ID table only where member_descr = 'O' but we need to take all data when member_ratio is lower from IS_ID table and for such fund_isin it should not take data from IS_ID_TST table check output fund_isin L000123, D123458...i think here logic will contradict as at the end the logic is to take all the data from IS_ID_TST table where member_descr ! = 'O' otherwise there will be duplicate from both table for same FUND_ISIN? For all other cases we should take the data from IS_ID_TST table M123456, F563458, G123456

Comment: and as we decided to take all the data from IS_ID table where member_ratio is low and for which the fund_isin does not exist in IS_ID_TST table then we also dont need this condition AND t1.member_descr = t2.member_descr because the member_descr can be different from both the table for same fund_isin..

Comment: i have updated question and added at the bottom insert statements and expected output

Comment: @Symonds you should keep the current one as before, and ask a new question I think.

Comment: sorry will it be confusing if i ask new question because we just need to modify bit logic here ?

Comment: sure i have created question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64044272/create-oracle-view-to-compare-data-based-on-conditions  thanks

Comment: is it very complex to write such view with the logic mentione ?