# create Oracle View to compare data based on conditions

Tags: oracle, select, view

I have below tables:

```
    CREATE TABLE
        IS_ID
        (        
            FUND_ISIN VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
            FUND_QUOTE_CRNY VARCHAR2(5),       
            MEMBER_DESCR VARCHAR2(5),
            MEMBER_RATIO NUMBER(19,8),
            ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE VARCHAR2(100)
        );
    
    CREATE TABLE
        IS_ID_TST
        (        
            FUND_ISIN VARCHAR2(12) NOT NULL,
            FUND_QUOTE_CRNY VARCHAR2(5),       
            MEMBER_DESCR VARCHAR2(5),
            MEMBER_RATIO NUMBER(19,8),
            ALLOCATIONASSETTYPE VARCHAR2(100)
        );
```

I want to create view such that:

1. for common `fund_isin` field value from both tables, check the `member_ratio` field for `member_descr = 'O'`and take all the rows for fund_isin from table where `member_ratio` field value is low. For `member_descr = 'O'`, if the `member_ratio` in `IS_ID_TST` table is less than 0 for any `fund_isin` then always take all the data from `IS_ID_TST` table(in this case we dont need to compare data from `IS_ID` table for low member ratio)
2. if the `fund_isin` exist in one table but not in another then take all those rows(bidirectional).
3. for all the other fund_isin, take all those rows only from table `IS_ID_TST` table(this might cover in point 1 and 2 )

Comment: for the point `For member_descr = 'O', if the member_ratio in IS_ID_TST table is less than 0 for any fund_isin then always take all the data from IS_ID_TST table(in this case we dont need to compare data from IS_ID table for low member ratio` ....Is this condition for only common records available in both tables or irrespective of whether it is available in both or not just always take the record with <0 value in ratio column from `IS_ID_TST` table ?

Comment: we always take the record with <0 value in member_ratio from IS_ID_TST table...we dont need to compare with IS_ID table for this...

Comment: That means for the common records we only need to consider ration value > 0. am I right ?

Comment: yes for member_descr = 'O' when member_ratio value > 0 from IS_ID_TST table then check common records from IS_ID  and IS_ID_TST table and take all the rows with low_ratio from respective table...previously for low ratio we were taking only rows with member_descr = 'O' from table but now we have to take all rows for respective fund_isin...

Comment: Ok. its quite complicated to think but I can validate the points you have mentioned in the question and see

Comment: yes may be i think i am explaining in complicated way ..

Comment: do you think its very complex and might not able to do in view ?

Comment: It is possible for sure and need some time from my end to come up with the right one

Comment: from your comment `previously for low ratio we were taking only rows with member_descr = 'O' from table but now we have to take all rows for respective fund_isin` .. this part again I got confused. Could you re-check and update the the question

Comment: yes for example please check the expected output for fund_isin L000123...previously for low member_ratio we were taking only rows where member_descr = 'O'...but now you can see for low member_ratio we have to take all rows and not only member_descr = 'O' for fund_isin..thats why there are 3 rows for fund_isin in the expected output

Comment: in my question also i mentioned that for member_descr = 'O', we have to take all rows for fund_isin where member_ratio is low and i think this is the point where difficulty lies ..because for example for fund_isin L000123 for member_descr = 'O' and which has low member_ratio we will take all the data from IS_ID table and we will not take data from IS_ID_TST table

Comment: Yes I am lost completely. Would it be possible to take 1 or 2 or max 3 `fund_isin ` which will cover all the cases

Comment: yes i tried to cover all this cases actually ...for example L000123 to take all rows from IS_ID table and not from IS_ID_TST table because it has low ratio  for member_descr = 'O' , fund_isin F000123 is to take all rows from IS_ID_TST table even if it does not have low ratio compared to IS_ID table  for member_descr = 'O' because member_ratio < 0 for this fund_isin, fund_isin H000526 is to take all rows from IS_ID table because it does not exist in IS_ID_TST table, fund_isin M123456, F563458, G123456 take all rows from IS_ID_TST table because it does not exist in IS_ID table

Comment: fund_isin D000123 to take all rows from IS_ID_TST table because it has low ratio compared to IS_ID table for member_descr = 'O' .....i think it covers every case right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you check following query, I have made all cases within `with` clause and then make union out of it.

***Edit:- After discussion and clarification with OP over chat***

We do not need `full join` any more and by accessing the table per each case it is re-written.

```
-- case 1
-- when fund_isin with member_ratio = 'O' present in both is_id and is_id_tst table
-- and the value of is_id.member_ratio < is_id_tst.memebr_ratio
-- logic --
-- the from clasuse says take all the records from is_id table 
-- by corelate the fund_isin (t1.fund_isin = t.fund_isin)
-- the subquery then finds record by joining both table is_id and is_id_tst for member_ratio = 'O'
-- and where the member_ratio is smaller (is_id_tst.member_ratio > is_id.member_ratio)
-- extra condition on is_id_tst table is the member_ratio value should be greater than 0 for member_descr='O'
WITH ratio_lower_is_id
AS
(SELECT *
   FROM is_id t
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1
     FROM is_id_tst t2
     JOIN is_id t1
       ON t2.fund_isin = t1.fund_isin
    WHERE t1.fund_isin = t.fund_isin
      AND t2.member_descr = 'O'
      AND t1.member_descr = 'O'
      AND t2.member_ratio > 0
      AND t2.member_ratio > 
          t1.member_ratio)
),
-- case 2
-- applies the same logic as in case 1 but then take records from is_id_tst table
-- where the member_ratio having lower value for record with member_descr='O'
-- in comparison with the record present in is_id table for memebr_descr='O'
ratio_lower_is_id_tst
AS
(SELECT *
   FROM is_id_tst t
  WHERE t.member_ratio > 0
    AND EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1
     FROM is_id t2
     JOIN is_id_tst t1
       ON t2.fund_isin = t1.fund_isin
    WHERE t1.fund_isin = t.fund_isin
      AND t2.member_descr = 'O'
      AND t1.member_descr = 'O'
      AND t2.member_ratio > 
          t1.member_ratio)
),
-- case 3
-- take all records from is_id_tst table for all each unique fund_isin 
-- where the member_ratio value is < 0 for record member_descr='O'
-- and is avaialble in is_id_tst table irrespective of what record for the same
-- fund_isin available in is_id table
ratio_minus_is_id_tst
AS
(SELECT *
   FROM is_id_tst t
  WHERE EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1
     FROM is_id_tst t1
    WHERE t1.fund_isin = t.fund_isin
      AND t1.member_descr = 'O'
      AND t1.member_ratio < 0)
),
-- case 4
-- take all the records from is_id table 
-- where the fund_isin is not available in is_id_tst table
only_in_is_id
AS
(
SELECT *
  FROM is_id t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 
      FROM is_id_tst t2
     WHERE t2.fund_isin = t1.fund_isin)
),
-- case 5
-- take all the records from is_id_tst table
-- where the fund_isin is not available in is_id table
only_in_is_id_tst
AS
(
SELECT *
  FROM is_id_tst t1
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 
      FROM is_id t2
     WHERE t2.fund_isin = t1.fund_isin)
)
-- finally once all the sets as per each case available
-- take each of them and do a union all for the final result set
-- one level sub query required only if we want to sort the result otherwise can be removed
-- and only union all of all sets from with clause is enough
select *
  from 
(
-- case1
select *
  from ratio_lower_is_id
union all
-- case 2
select *
  from ratio_lower_is_id_tst
union all
-- case 3
select *
  from ratio_minus_is_id_tst
union all
-- case 4
select *
  from only_in_is_id
union all
-- case 5
select *
  from only_in_is_id_tst
)
order by fund_isin;
```

Comment: for fund_isin H000526 we have to take all rows from IS_IS table because it does not exist in IS_ID_TST table...its point 2 in question

Comment: one question here..why did you make joins for t1.fund_quote_crny = t2.fund_quote_crny
AND    t1.member_descr = t2.member_descr ..in some place because i think fund_isin is the key for comparision between table and member_descr value can be different also the other fields from both table for same fund_isin ?

Comment: for `H000526` , there one record with 'O' and  onw with 'C' but result says 2 records with 'C' , how ? And i made join only for where we need pair records to check. I am not sure without this join how do you imagine and it would be then entirely different logic. e.g `D000123` has three records with `MEMBER_DESCR` null in `IS_ID` table and which logic covers this ?

Comment: sorry my bad it was typo mistake..i corrected the records in question for H000526  and D000123 ...actually pair records means ? because for member_descr = 'O' normally we are just comparing the record based on common fund_isin or fund_isin does not exist at all ?

Comment: When I say pair means, e.g the first case says we need to compare the common records between `is_id` and `is_id_tst` and then take the record with lower `member ratio`. If you say to only take `fund_isin` to compare then which record from is_id` will be compared with which record from `is_id_tst` ? And also If you take only `fund_isin` it would be a cross join and then how you will compare ?

Comment: for comparision i think the basic rule is we need to take common fund_isin where member_descr = 'O' and check their member_ratio value and take all the rows which has lower ratio...we can also applies this for point 2...check fund_isin where member_descr = 'O' and check if it exist in any of the table and take all the rows ...please correct me here why do we require other joins with t1.fund_quote_crny = t2.fund_quote_crny ?

Comment: In earlier comments you said `...previously for low ratio we were taking only rows with member_descr = 'O' from table but now we have to take all rows for respective fund_isin`. If this the case the why we should bother about only 'O' records .....regarding `fund_quote_crny` join I see in the example data all are same and that's why join......I really doubt now about my understanding on the topic...no idea how to proceed..

Comment: sorry for confusion...for fund_isin we have to check and compare the value for member_ratio only where member_descr = 'O' and take all the rows when the condition is satisfied...actually there might be case where fund_quote_crncy are not equal thats why i asked do we really require this join...

Comment: @Symonds, I would suggest really to think and edit the question and mention examples for each case what should happen in the question itself. Otherwise this discussion will never end I believe. :(

Comment: can we take discussion in chat sorry ? :( i think we are really close where we will be on the same page....i really didnt know that it will be more complicated when i changed logic little bit after our first question :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222087/discussion-between-symonds-and-sujitmohanty30).

Comment: Check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e70b67ab5e37b0ef841571ddaf53a503 .... I added an extra or condition to case `ratio_minus_is_id_tst` to take the record with `O` where it doesn't exists in `is_id` table.